# Как выбрать элемент ListView программно?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Приветствую. Нужно выбрать самый первый элемент из коллекции ListView программно, как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListView.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Решение для WPF.

Answer (score 1):

```
listView.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

Comment: "object" не содержит определения для "Selected", и не был найден метод расширения "Selected", принимающий тип "object" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

------------------------------------------------------------------
Я пробовал, к сожалению, не работает. :(

Comment: Пардон, не обратил внимание на тег WPF.